# How to insert a superscript label in QGIS 2.14 print composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I'm trying to get superscript in my legend label in my print composer and am struggling. I've tried a few of the methods [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/192842/subscript-labels-in-qgis-legends) but don't really understand how to make character map idea work in osx. Specifically how to find the appropriate symbol. I've tried to copy and paste other symbols into the legend title but that hasn't worked

I tried creating what I need in word and copying across but the superscript characters don't reflect in the legend title. So finally I went with a render as HTML text box as a work around which is a little big even though `size = 0`.

```
<font face = 'lantinghei sc' size = '0'>mg/m<sup>3</sup></font>
```

[image]

So, could somebody please explain either how to get mapped characters from osx El Capitan into the legend title or how to shrink the html text to useable format?

---

Apparently you can use basic CSS for the html features. This has a decent workaround for what I need. Anyone know if you can do anything like this in the Legend title?

```
<style>
p {
font-family: lantinghei sc;
font-size: 5pt;
text-align: justify;
}
</style>
<body>
    <p>mg/m<sup>3</sup></p>
</body>
```