# QGIS 3.10.7 - Subscript/superscript in the legend text

Tags: qgis, legend, layouts, text

I'm trying to add subscript/superscript in the legend text of a layout in QGIS. I can do it in a simple text box just click on View as HTML and then using for example `<sub>` in order to write a subscript.

How could I do this in the legend text? I don't find anything to enable HTML on the legend property panel.

Comment: I have forgotten the example: in a simple text box I just  write:  <sub>+subscript text

Comment: Have you checked this answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/192929/63384

Comment: Thank you very much for answer.